# Perofrming the operations on RDD PySpark

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I using Python Spark API while getting file name having an issue. For example

```
recordDataFrame=originalDataFrame \
                    .withColumn('file_name',input_file_name())
```

Added the file_name column to dataFrame.The column is added to the dataFrame

```
recordDataFrame.take(1)
```

Above shows the column with value
But when I am converting dataFrame to RDD or looping over RDD file_name column don't have any value.

For example,

```
rdd_data=recordDataFrame.rdd
print(rdd_data.take(1))
```

This will show file_name column with blank value
Or if I do looping over the dataFrame directly then also file name don't have any value

```
recordDataFrame.foreach(process_data)
```

But if I pass the static value to file_name instead of using input_file_name() while adding column then everything works fine

Comment: This is a bug. When data is passed to Python executor required context which is used to get file name is lost.  Should be fixed in 2.0.0

Comment: Thanks @zero323 .Do you have any idea how can we get workaround with this using current spark 1.6?Basically need file name for each record in dataFrame. Is there any way of achieving this using pySpark?

Comment: Yes there is, but I doubt you'll like it and it a serious hack. I'll post some ideas in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug which has been resolved in 2.0.0.

**Disclaimer**:

These are serious hacks and should be avoided unless you're desperate. Also non of these have been properly tested. If you can it is better to update.

1. Trigger a shuffle after loading the data for example with:

   ```
   recordDataFrame.repartition("file_name")
   ```

   or

   ```
   recordDataFrame.orderBy("file_name")
   ```
2. Truncate lineage as shown in [high-performance-spark/high-performance-spark-examples](https://github.com/high-performance-spark/high-performance-spark-examples/blob/0e225c46ec90107aa7301015f86f5becf8bac7a7/high_performance_pyspark/SQLLineage.py)
    (code is GPL licensed so it cannot be reproduced here but the main idea is to access internal Java RDD, cache it and recreate DataFrame):

   ```
   cutLineage(recordDataFrame)
   ```

Comment: Thanks zero323 for answer .The hack you suggested works without any issue.
As of now will use the above hack and once 2.0 is release will update to that one.

Comment: @Yogesh It [has been released](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-2-0-0.html) :)

Comment: But its still in beta.Not a stable version yet right?

Comment: just checked its release yesterday only Spark 2.0.0 (Jul 26 2016) thanks for the info.